# How to create a public audit record with OpenSSL?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I maintain my own CA for internal use using OpenSSL's CA mechanism, and so far it worked fine. Now Chrome complains that there are no "public audit records" for my CA.

I already created a public CRL, but that's not good enough for Chrome - it keeps complaining about my sites not being "verified".

Hence my question: is it possible to create a public audit record using OpenSSL?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [What exactly does it mean when Chrome reports a certificate 'does not have public audit records'?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/52834/29925) on [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I did not think it was a bad question, and I even upvoted it. I'm interested in finding a solution too. The problem is Stack Overflow is not the forum for it. If you want to work on this together, then email me offline: *noloader, gmail account*.

Answer (score 0):

Public audit record = [Certificate Transparency](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2668154) record.

Currently it is required only by Google Chrome in new issued EV certificates ([source](http://www.certificate-transparency.org/ev-ct-plan)) as a solution to the broken PKI trust model. In future we can probably see Google pushing its adoption further.

Comment: Very nice, but how to make it with OpenSSL?

Comment: I would try to combine knowledge from [RFC6962](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6962) and [OpenSSL guide about issuing certificate requests with extensions](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509v3_config.html#ARBITRARY-EXTENSIONS). Then `openssl req -new -config yourconfig.cfg ...` will add your extensions to the CSR.